# Model binding when passing arrays to child component

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to do a simple thing.  I have a table of entities, and each entity has a checkbox. Plus, in the table header, there is a global checkbox, so that I can select all of the entities at once.

When I work with static data there is no problem, everything works as expected. For example:

```
data() {
  allUnitsSelected: false,
  units: [
    {
      selected: false
    },
    {
      selected: false
    },
    {
      selected: false
    },
  ]
},

watch: {
  allUnitsSelected() {
    this.units.forEach((unit) => {
      unit.selected = this.allUnitsSelected
    })
  }
}
```

And HTML:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" v-model="allUnitsSelected"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="unit in units" :class="{ selected: unit.selected }">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="unit.selected">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

But when I pass this array as a component property it stops working. Basically I retrieve an object from server, which has units array, and I pass this object to component. Doesn't matter if I pass an object or array. Something like this:

```
export default {
  props: ['item'],
  data() {
     allUnitsSelected: false
  }
}
```

In HTML I use item.units instead of just units. The v-for works and I got item list, however I can't update their "selected" property. In chrome dev tools in Vue inspector I can see that the property gets updated, but the checkbox does not.

Why might this happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some code of the component you are trying to create?

Comment: Ehy Victor, helping you if you provide a jsFiddle will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have read documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats

The thing is if I change element in array of object vue.js doesn't track it until I use $set...